# C# reflection generic property type

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Say that I have a class like this:

```
public class TestClass <T>
{
    public T Prop { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to identify that the property type is `T`, not the actual type that is passed e.g. `int`
In order to clarify it a bit more:

```
TestClass<int> tc=new TestClass<int>();
tc.GetType().GetProperty("prop").PropertyType.Name; //this returns int, but I need "T"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a `TestClass<int>` instance, you have a reified generic type - the property *is* `int`, not `T`.

To get at the actual generic type, you can use `GetGenericTypeDefinition`:

```
var genericType = tc.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
var typeName = genericType.GetProperty("Prop").PropertyType.Name;
```

And if you want to distinguish between actual types and generic type arguments, you can use `Type.IsGenericParameter`:

```
genericType.GetProperty("Prop").PropertyType.IsGenericParameter // true
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I probably finally understand `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you are are using C# 6, and require the generic type argument's name within it's defining class, you can get away without using reflection at all:

```
var name = nameof(T);  // "T"
```

If you need the the generic type argument's name outside of it's class, you will need to use reflection (see [Luaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148640/c-sharp-reflection-generic-property-type/35148711#35148711).)